# Can't install the Vulkan SDK from tarball on Fedora Linux

Tags: c++, c++11, cmake, fedora, vulkan

I tried to install the Vulkan SDK from the tarball from the LunarG website (version 1.3.224.1) on Fedora 37 beta (I also tried it on Nobara Linux 36) and kept getting these errors.

```
In function ‘std::_Require<std::__not_<std::__is_tuple_like<_Tp> >, std::is_move_constructible<_Tp>, std::is_move_assignable<_Tp> > std::swap(_Tp&, _Tp&) [with _Tp = Json::Value::ValueHolder]’,
    inlined from ‘void Json::Value::swapPayload(Json::Value&)’ at /home/said/vulkan/1.3.224.1/source/VulkanTools/submodules/jsoncpp/dist/jsoncpp.cpp:2967:12,
    inlined from ‘bool Json::Reader::readValue()’ at /home/said/vulkan/1.3.224.1/source/VulkanTools/submodules/jsoncpp/dist/jsoncpp.cpp:433:31:
/usr/include/c++/12/bits/move.h:205:7: error: ‘v.Json::Value::value_’ may be used uninitialized [-Werror=maybe-uninitialized]
  205 |       __a = _GLIBCXX_MOVE(__b);
      |       ^~~
/home/said/vulkan/1.3.224.1/source/VulkanTools/submodules/jsoncpp/dist/jsoncpp.cpp: In member function ‘bool Json::Reader::readValue()’:
/home/said/vulkan/1.3.224.1/source/VulkanTools/submodules/jsoncpp/dist/jsoncpp.cpp:432:11: note: ‘v’ declared here
  432 |     Value v;
      |           ^
In function ‘std::_Require<std::__not_<std::__is_tuple_like<_Tp> >, std::is_move_constructible<_Tp>, std::is_move_assignable<_Tp> > std::swap(_Tp&, _Tp&) [with _Tp = Json::Value::ValueHolder]’,
    inlined from ‘void Json::Value::swapPayload(Json::Value&)’ at /home/said/vulkan/1.3.224.1/source/VulkanTools/submodules/jsoncpp/dist/jsoncpp.cpp:2967:12,
    inlined from ‘bool Json::Reader::readValue()’ at /home/said/vulkan/1.3.224.1/source/VulkanTools/submodules/jsoncpp/dist/jsoncpp.cpp:446:33:
/usr/include/c++/12/bits/move.h:205:7: error: ‘v.Json::Value::value_’ may be used uninitialized [-Werror=maybe-uninitialized]
  205 |       __a = _GLIBCXX_MOVE(__b);
      |       ^~~
/home/said/vulkan/1.3.224.1/source/VulkanTools/submodules/jsoncpp/dist/jsoncpp.cpp: In member function ‘bool Json::Reader::readValue()’:
/home/said/vulkan/1.3.224.1/source/VulkanTools/submodules/jsoncpp/dist/jsoncpp.cpp:445:13: note: ‘v’ declared here
  445 |       Value v;
      |             ^
In function ‘std::_Require<std::__not_<std::__is_tuple_like<_Tp> >, std::is_move_constructible<_Tp>, std::is_move_assignable<_Tp> > std::swap(_Tp&, _Tp&) [with _Tp = Json::Value::ValueHolder]’,
    inlined from ‘void Json::Value::swapPayload(Json::Value&)’ at /home/said/vulkan/1.3.224.1/source/VulkanTools/submodules/jsoncpp/dist/jsoncpp.cpp:2967:12,
    inlined from ‘bool Json::OurReader::readValue()’ at /home/said/vulkan/1.3.224.1/source/VulkanTools/submodules/jsoncpp/dist/jsoncpp.cpp:1355:31:
/usr/include/c++/12/bits/move.h:205:7: error: ‘v.Json::Value::value_’ may be used uninitialized [-Werror=maybe-uninitialized]
  205 |       __a = _GLIBCXX_MOVE(__b);
      |       ^~~
/home/said/vulkan/1.3.224.1/source/VulkanTools/submodules/jsoncpp/dist/jsoncpp.cpp: In member function ‘bool Json::OurReader::readValue()’:
/home/said/vulkan/1.3.224.1/source/VulkanTools/submodules/jsoncpp/dist/jsoncpp.cpp:1354:11: note: ‘v’ declared here
 1354 |     Value v;
      |           ^
In function ‘std::_Require<std::__not_<std::__is_tuple_like<_Tp> >, std::is_move_constructible<_Tp>, std::is_move_assignable<_Tp> > std::swap(_Tp&, _Tp&) [with _Tp = Json::Value::ValueHolder]’,
    inlined from ‘void Json::Value::swapPayload(Json::Value&)’ at /home/said/vulkan/1.3.224.1/source/VulkanTools/submodules/jsoncpp/dist/jsoncpp.cpp:2967:12,
    inlined from ‘bool Json::OurReader::readValue()’ at /home/said/vulkan/1.3.224.1/source/VulkanTools/submodules/jsoncpp/dist/jsoncpp.cpp:1392:33:
/usr/include/c++/12/bits/move.h:205:7: error: ‘v.Json::Value::value_’ may be used uninitialized [-Werror=maybe-uninitialized]
  205 |       __a = _GLIBCXX_MOVE(__b);
      |       ^~~
/home/said/vulkan/1.3.224.1/source/VulkanTools/submodules/jsoncpp/dist/jsoncpp.cpp: In member function ‘bool Json::OurReader::readValue()’:
/home/said/vulkan/1.3.224.1/source/VulkanTools/submodules/jsoncpp/dist/jsoncpp.cpp:1391:13: note: ‘v’ declared here
 1391 |       Value v;
      |             ^
```

I tried going through the CMake files to try to disable the `-Werror=maybe-uninitialized` option but I'm not familiar with CMake so couldn't find a way to do that. I also tried going through the C++ source code itself and trying to fix it that way but still could not fix the issue.

Thank you very much.

Comment: A brief check shows vulkan-tools to be an available rpm package that can be installed via dnf. Any particular reason you're attempting to build it yourself?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik THANK YOU SO MUCH. To give a bit of context, I thought I had to run the vulkansdk script in the tarball before I could source the setup-env.sh file but it turns out that is not the case. Not only that but I already had the vulkan-tools package installed. Again, thank you very much